# music does not stop in eclipse

Tags: java, android

I have one button and I want click play click again stop, but music will not stop and play again for second click. How can i fix it?

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this , R.raw.crash);
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        } else {
            mp.start(); 
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }           
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare MediaPlayer as a local variable like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = null; // local in your activity
```

and in your onClickListener():

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
      if(mp = null)
      {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.crash);
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
      }
      else
      {
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        {
          mp.stop();
          mp = null;
        }
      }
}
});
```

Good luck!